# No checkpoint files are created in my simple application

Tags: apache-flink

I have the following simple flink application running within IDE, and I do a checkpoint every 5 seconds, and would like to write the checkpoint data into directory `file:///d:/applog/out/mycheckpoint/`, but after running for a while, i stop the application,but I didn't find anything under the directory `file:///d:/applog/out/mycheckpoint/`

The code is:

```
import java.util.Date

import io.github.streamingwithflink.util.DateUtil
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.{ListState, ListStateDescriptor}
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsStateBackend
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.{FunctionInitializationContext, FunctionSnapshotContext}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointedFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}
    object SourceFunctionExample {

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
        env.setParallelism(4)
        env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointInterval(5 * 1000)
        env.getCheckpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION)
        env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("file:///d:/applog/out/mycheckpoint/"))
        val numbers: DataStream[Long] = env.addSource(new ReplayableCountSource)
        numbers.print()

        env.execute()
      }

    }


class ReplayableCountSource extends SourceFunction[Long] with CheckpointedFunction {

  var isRunning: Boolean = true
  var cnt: Long = _
  var offsetState: ListState[Long] = _

  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[Long]): Unit = {

    while (isRunning && cnt < Long.MaxValue) {
      ctx.getCheckpointLock.synchronized {
        // increment cnt
        cnt += 1
        ctx.collect(cnt)
      }
      Thread.sleep(200)
    }

  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = isRunning = false

  override def snapshotState(snapshotCtx: FunctionSnapshotContext): Unit = {
    println("snapshotState is called at " + DateUtil.format(new Date) + s", cnt is ${cnt}")
    // remove previous cnt
    offsetState.clear()
    // add current cnt
    offsetState.add(cnt)
  }

  override def initializeState(initCtx: FunctionInitializationContext): Unit = {
    // obtain operator list state to store the current cnt

    val desc = new ListStateDescriptor[Long]("offset", classOf[Long])
    offsetState = initCtx.getOperatorStateStore.getListState(desc)

    // initialize cnt variable from the checkpoint
    val it = offsetState.get()
    cnt = if (null == it || !it.iterator().hasNext) {
      -1L
    } else {
      it.iterator().next()
    }

    println("initializeState is called at " + DateUtil.format(new Date) + s", cnt is ${cnt}")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the application on Windows and Linux and in both cases the checkpoint files were created as expected.

Note that the program keeps running if a checkpoint fails, for example due to some permission errors or invalid path.

Flink logs a `WARN` message with the exception that caused the checkpoint to fail.

Comment: Thanks @fabian-hueske for the reply, i tried and hit an exception:  AbstractFileStateBackend#validatePath checks that scheme should be provided

Comment: OK, thanks for checking! Will try to reproduce the issue on a Windows machine.

Comment: Thank you @fabian-hueske for the great effort!

Comment: I tested the program on Windows and it worked for me. I've updated my answer. Please check if Flink logs exceptions about failed checkpoints (which do not cause the program to fail).

Comment: Sure, thanks @fabian-hueske, I will investigate more to find the reason to fail